# Transcendence Degrees of Composite Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra

The problem is as follows:

> $\mbox{trdeg} (E_1E_2/K) \leq \mbox{trdeg}(E_1/K) + \mbox{trdeg}(E_2/K)$

where $E_1, E_2$ are intermediate fields of the extension $K\subseteq F$. I understand this should be a straightforward exercise, but I'm getting caught up in writing out the details.

My first thought was to go the way of contradiction. Say $S$ and $T$ are transcendence bases for $E_1$ and $E_2$ respectively. Then, let $W$ be a transcendence basis of $E_1E_2$. Suppose $|W| > |S| + |T|$.

I think we will end up contradicting the maximality of $S$ and $T$, but I don't see where that comes from. Any help would be appreciated. TIA.

Comment: Why not work directly, show that $S$ and $T$ can be chosen disjoint, and then verify that $E_1E_2$ is algebraic over $K(S\cup T)$?

Comment: How would I show that $S$ and $T$ can be chosen to be disjoint? I think I understand that if they are chosen to be disjoint, that $E_1E_2$ is algebraic over $K(S\cup T)$ since $F$ must be algebraic over $K(S \cup T)$, and it is an intermediate field.

Comment: You can always take an element of, say, $S$, and add/multiply by an element of $K$ and still have a transcendence basis for $E_1$ over $K$. So just perturb them enough to ensure they are disjoint. E.g., take $U=S\cap T$, and let $S’=(S\setminus U)\cup (U+1)$ and $T’=T$. You just need to verify no element of $U+1$ can lie in $T$, which should not be difficult.

Comment: How do we know that $S \cup T$ is a maximal algebraically independent set? We would need that to show that $|S \cup T|$ is trdeg($E_1E_2$), right?

Comment: No, you do not; if $F/K$ is an extension, and $X\subseteq F$ is such that $F/K(X)$ is algebraic, then $X$ contains a transcendence basis for $F$ over $K$. If you needed to prove what you claim, you would have *equality*, not the inequality you are trying to prove. (Consider for instance $E_1=\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ and $E_2=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\pi})$).